# Error while creating a new web application in MOSS 2007 in a stand alone server farm

Tags: infrastructure, 2007, error, deployment

I am getting following error while creating any new web application on the server:

1. "An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPWebApplication Name=SPsupport-17777 Parent=SPWebService is being updated by EUROPE\SPSvc-Ams11267-S, in the w3wp process, on machine AMSDC1-S-1267.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict."
2. "The specified SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content TEST Parent=SPDatabaseServiceInstance has been upgraded to a newer version of SharePoint. Please upgrade this SharePoint application server before attempting to access this object."
3. In Event Viewer I am also getting an error like:
   "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint `FK_Dependencies1_Objects`. The conflict occurred in database `Dev_Config_01`, table "dbo.Dependencies", column 'ObjectId'.
   The statement has been terminated."

As got from some forums, I performed the below steps:

1. Stopping wss timer job
2. Copying the cache.ini file from C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\application data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config folder.
3. Clearing all the .xml files except cache.ini
4. Edit the cache.ini with a value 1
5. Starting the timer job

Still I get the same error. I tried the above steps many times.

I need a solution for this issue. Are these issues related to anything on the software patches installed on the server or MOSS?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this one before. That time it was a connectivity issue between SharePoint and the database server. You should check system log files on SQL server and SharePoint regarding hardware or connectivity problems.

Answer (score 1):

No there was no patch installtion in the server farm. Also the server was not upgraded to any new version.

What i did to resolve this:

1) Restarted all serach services from Central Administration. A new serach database created for the server.
2) Followed the steps as mentioned below twice with a server reboot

Stopping wss timer job 
Copying the cache.ini file from C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\application data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config folder. 
Clearing all the .xml files except cache.ini 
Edit the cache.ini with a value 1 
Starting the timer job

3) At last i ran the configuration wizard. I selected the option disconnect the server from server farm and revert back again. Selected the option as not to disconnect from server farm and ran the wizard successfully.

Then i rechecked by creating new web application. And i able to create it without any error.

Not sure which one among the above hit the line.But i was able to get rid of the problem without reconfiguring the farm.

Thank You >>>..

S

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading a SharePoint instance to a different version will upgrade the content databases too. Normally if you connect a SharePoint database that has come from an older version of SharePoint, a job will run to upgrade the content database as it is added.

From the errors you have provided, I can only surmise that somehow the versions are out of sync.

You could try re-creating your content-test database.

Did this start occuring after installing a patch?

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any means try to attach a content database from another SharePoint server? Just looking at the error message makes me wonder if you aren't trying to attach a content database of a SharePoint 2007 server that is a new version.

Are you trying to do this in a farm. In that case, are all your servers updated to the same version?